# ServiceWorker in React and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

When creating javascript-based React projects, installing a Service Worker is just a matter of changing `serviceWorker.unregister()` to `serviceWorker.register()` on index.jsx.

With such project structure:

```
- src
   |- index.jsx
   |- serviceWorker.js
```

When this code gets built, the `/build` folder will look as followed:

```
- build
   |- static
   |   |- css
   |   |- js
   |   |- media
   |
   |- index.html
   |- service-worker.js
```

This will work fine and will result in the Service Worker being registered properly.

---

On the other hand, when setting up a project in Typescript, given the same project structure (where the `js` / `jsx` files are `ts` / `tsx` instead), the `/build` will look something similar:

```
- build
   |- static
   |   |- js
   |       |- bundled-js.chunk.js
   |       |- bundled-js2.chunk.js
   |       |- ..
   |
   |- index.html
```

So it seems Typescript builds the `serviceWorker` bundling it with all the other js files.

This will then result in the Service Worker not being registered, with the following error in console:

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://example.com/') with script ('https://example.com/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

The live site with the error can be seen [here](https://alessiopetrin.com); The open source code can be found [here](https://github.com/ale917k/portfoliov4/tree/master/client).

Any idea of what I may be doing wrong?

Any tip is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Typescript doesn't bundle, your bundler will, are you using webpack.?

Comment: Ah that's nice to know, thought ts was working as a bundler too - I guess I am anyway as the project has been created with `create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking at your code your using Create React App,.  This uses webpack, and it's that what is bundling, it's nothing to do with Typescript, the same would happen for Javascript when it gets bundled.

The problem is overriding the webpack config's is not easy, there is CRACO -> https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#webpack-api

But even then it's a little tricky!!    You need to tell webpack not to bundle `service-worker.js`, Also I would take the register bit out of the `server-worker`, as that can be bundled and wants to be included in your bundle.

The simplest option might be just to compile the webworker separately   with Typescript directly.  And again, keep the register bit separate inside your normal build.